# How to configure AWS EC2/Lightsail instance to support a masked url redirect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-ec2, subdomain

I'm trying to create a url redirect for a subdomain on my Lightsail instance, currently the redirect is working with the exception the ip:port are visible in the navigation pane of the browser when it should read subdomain.domain.com . I spoke with the customer support of my DNS (Namecheap) and I was told to contact AWS. I myself couldn't find documentation on this from AWS, and because of my tier level I cannot get direct support from AWS. Has anyone had this issue, or know of a way I can rectify it?

Comment: How did you configure your route53?

Comment: Lightsail is a server.  Asking about how to do something "on Lightsail" is like asking how to do something "on a computer."  More detail about exactly what web server software is running and how you have configured it and the cascade of requests and responses you are seeing.